# "woodsy" vs. "woody" for "covered with trees/wooded" in NAmEng

Tags: word-usage, formality, dialects, north-american-english

What's the difference between those terms?

Context would be a quaint little village nestled into a hillside covered with trees, sort of like [this one](http://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photo-village-hillside-transylvania-romania-nestled-green-sunny-day-image61312549).

**WOODY**:

> **4**. Abounding in trees; wooded. (American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)
>
> **1**. abounding with woods; wooded. (Random House Kennerman Webster's College Dictionary)
>
> **2**. abounding in trees. (WordNet by Farlex)
>
> [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/woody)
>
> **1**. abounding or overgroon with woods [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/woody)
>
> **1**. abounding with wood; wooded [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/woody)
>
> **1**. (Of an area of land) covered with trees:
>   *a woody dale* [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/woody)
>
> **3**. *adjective* (GROUP OF TREES) having many ​trees: *They ​lived in a ​remote ​house set high on a woody ​hillside*. [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/woody)
>
> *countryside* [**boisé**](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/woody/624769) (Collins-Robert French and English Dictionary, Éd. 1985)

**WOODSY**:

> 1. Relating to, characteristic of, or suggestive of the woods. (American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)
> 2. (*Forestry*) *US and Canadian* of, reminiscent of, or connected with woods: a woodsy mountain hideaway. (CED)
> 3. abounding in trees (WordNet by Farlex)
>
> [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/woodsy)
>
> 1. having many trees : covered with trees [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/woodsy)
>
> *North American* Of, relating to, or characteristic of wood or woodlands:
>   *trails through woodsy countryside* [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/woodsy)
>
> (*informal*, *especially North American English*) covered with trees; connected with woods [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/woodsy)
>
> *US, informal* 1. having many trees : covered with trees
>   *a woodsy area* [MWLD](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/woodsy)
>
> (*US*) *countryside* boisé (Collins-Robert French and English Dictionary, Éd. 1985)

[**Ngram**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=woody+area%2Cwoodsy+area%2Cwoody+landscape%2Cwoodsy+landscape%2Cwoody+setting%2Cwoodsy+setting%2Cwoody+hillside%2Cwoodsy+hillside&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwoody%20area%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoodsy%20area%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoody%20landscape%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoodsy%20landscape%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoody%20setting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoodsy%20setting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoody%20hillside%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoodsy%20hillside%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: You mention NAmE vernacular. Please provide some more context for your question- you may be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I would advise against using *woodsy* unless you want to affect a colloquial American tone. To my Canadian ear it sounds as ridiculous as, say, *unwieldsy* instead of *unwieldy*.

Comment: In addition to @Anonym's comment, 'woody' primarily and very strongly means 'made of wood', so "that lot of land is very woody" sounds weird, because a piece of land can't consist of the material wood. In 'a very woody area' it is forced to mean 'having many trees'.

Comment: @Mitch That's why I was considering using "woodsy" instead. Tone should be colloquial.

Comment: @Mitch Here we would call that *a wooded area*.

Comment: @Anonym What if I want to affect a colloquial tone? Will "woodsy" be acceptable in that case?

Comment: I would tend to use "wooded" in most cases where a piece of land with trees is being described.  "Woody" and "woodsy" are more used to describe something from a decor standpoint.

Comment: @HotLicks Does "woodsy" really sound ridiculous like Anonym commented?

Comment: @Elian - One might say, eg, "a woodsy campsite".  It doesn't sound ridiculous, but it's not all that idiomatic.  "Wooded campsite" would better convey the idea of a site within an area of trees, while "woodsy campsite" suggests an "aura" of trees -- there might be trees, or it might be that there's just a wood fence with trees painted on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Woodsy*** is informal. Really, that's All there Is to it. Informal Usage can Sometimes be comical, intentionally or Otherwise.

> Even back in high school I figured I'd be doing something science-y for a living.

This Kind of Usage can Also be a Term of Endearment, akin to baby talk.

***Woody***, on the other hand, is perfectly acceptable even in formal contexts, even though it does sound a bit silly.

Comment: I think there’s more to it than that.  *Woody* can be used to describe something that smells like wood; oak or cedar have particular odors for example.  ***woodsy***, on the other hand, can be used to describe to smell of the woods in general- a mixture of rotting leaves, pine pitch, bark, pollen etc.

Comment: @Jim: In other words, it means _sylvan_. So why not just say sylvan.

Comment: Because I didn’t think of it - perhaps because I don’t quite equate the two in my mind.  I think of sylvan as more describing the woods as a whole.

Comment: @Jim: I don't blame you. For a moment I thought it would be ironic ... if I were talking to a Penn_sylvan_ia resident ... Hey ... Go Coyotes! (Sorry, I couldn't resist).

Answer (score 2):

A person or object is typically woodsy if it is reminiscent of the woods. Outdoorsy is a synonym. There is no literal wood needed. Think of a lumberjack.

Woody typically refers to a wooded area, and literally refers to trees.

Comment: So when the Mayo surgeon referred to the "woody tissue" around the area of a prior hand surgery he was saying there were trees in there?

Comment: One can always use a literal term figuratively. An a--hole literally refers to a hole in an ass. Calling someone an a--hole means something quite different. :-)